# How to store UUID as an alphanumeric in nodejs

Tags: node.js

Node-uuid provides an excellent package to generate uuid

https://github.com/broofa/node-uuid

```
// Generate a v4 (random) id
uuid.v4(); // -> '110ec58a-a0f2-4ac4-8393-c866d813b8d1'
```

However, it does not provide a way to encode it in base64 or alphanumeric string.

Is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: `v4.replace(/-/g,"")`?

Comment: It is in hex format. Ideally I would like to keep it a bit shorter

Answer (score 2):

Install;

https://github.com/RGBboy/urlsafe-base64

Then;

```
var uuid = require('node-uuid');
var base64 = require('urlsafe-base64');

base64.encode(Buffer(uuid.v4()));
```

Comment: I believe the buffer base64 is not url safe?

Comment: It's not urlsafe, you did not ask for url safe base64. I'll update my answer to reflect