# How to create anonymized email address

Tags: node.js, email, sendgrid, anonymize

I need to implement an anonymized email adress feature in my website, much like airbnb and homeaway do.

They create an anonymous address for each conversation between renter and landlord.

For example, homeaway has 
09834b6-5apf-4731-3932-8ef5232dsd742a@messages.homeaway.com

And airbnb has 
541kfgry7hnh343gnjvv23423t08k4g@reply.airbnb.com

(the ids leading @ have been altered).

Airbnb reference:
http://blog.airbnb.com/introducing-anonymized-email-addresses-airbnb/

I'm using node.js and sendgrid for sending emails. What is the process behind this that I should be using?

Answer (score 0):

The homeaway esample looks like a UUID string. Check this on how to generate UUID strings.

[How to store UUID as an alphanumeric in nodejs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24947035/how-to-store-uuid-as-an-alphanumeric-in-nodejs)